# RxSwift - Queue observables of different type from Singleton

Tags: swift, queue, rx-swift

I have a Singleton class (actually it's going to do web-scraping, but simplified here) with some public available functions. The functions all return a `Single<T>` but of different types.

It could look like this:

```
class Singleton {
    static let shared = Singleton()
    private init() { }

    func doSomethingInt() -> Single<Int> {
        return Single.just(1)
            .delay(3, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    }

    func doSomethingString() -> Single<String> {
        return Single.just("Wow")
            .delay(3, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    }
}
```

When someone calls `Singleton.shared.doSomthingInt()`, the function should be placed on a queue, not executing until it's passed through the queue. The next observable in the queue should not start executing before everything before it has completed. Ideally `Singleton` would have a function which would delay the execution of every functions that is passed onto it. Something like this:

```
private func placeInQueue<T: Any>(operation: Single<T>) -> Single<T> {
    // place in some magic shared queue
    return operation
}
```

And then I could just chain this function in the beginning of the functions that should be placed in the queue, like this:

```
func doSomethingString() -> Single<String> {
    let operation = Single.just("Wow")
        .delay(3, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    return placeInQueue(operation)
}
```

I feel like this should be possible with a `concat` operation somehow, but I havn't been able to solve it yet.

**Any clues?**

Answer (score 0):

I've created this class, which seems to be working :)

Maybe these is an issue with the what scheduler it is running on. At least, if I add some operations to the queue, each with a 3 second delay on the `MainScheduler`, I can see that some of the queued up operations end up completing more or less 3,5~4 seconds after the previous operation has completed. It's not that big an issue for me though :)

```
class ObservableQueue {
    init() { }

    private var queueArray = [(operation: Observable<Void>, id: Double)]()

    /// Adding the `operation` to an internal queue. Starts execution of the `operation` when all previous operations in the queue had sendt an stop event.
    func placeInQueue<T: Any>(_ operation: Single<T>) -> Single<T> {
        let operationId = createId()
        let queuedOperation = currentQueue()
            .flatMap { _ -> Single<T> in
                return operation
            }
            .do(
                onNext: { [weak self] _ in self?.removeFromQueue(id: operationId) },
                onError: { [weak self] _ in self?.removeFromQueue(id: operationId)
            })
        let queueableOperation = operation
            .map { _ in return () }
            .asObservable()
            .catchErrorJustReturn(())
        addToQueue(queueableOperation, id: operationId)
        return queuedOperation
    }

    private func createId() -> Double {
        var operationId: Double = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        while (queueArray.contains { $0.id == operationId }) {
            operationId = Date().timeIntervalSince1970
        }
        return operationId
    }

    private func currentQueue() -> Single<Void> {
        var queue = queueArray.map{ $0.operation }
        if queue.isEmpty {
            queue = [Observable.just(())]
        }
        return Observable.concat(queue).takeLast(1).asSingle()
    }

    private func addToQueue(_ operation: Observable<Void>, id: Double) {
        queueArray.append((operation: operation, id: id))
    }

    private func removeFromQueue(id: Double) {
        guard let index = (queueArray.index { $0.id == id }) else { return }
        queueArray.remove(at: index)
    }
}
```

Here's how I use it:

```
private let queue = ObservableQueue()

func doSomethingInt() -> Single<Int> {
    let operation = Single.just(1)
        .delay(3, scheduler: MainScheduler.instance)
    return queue.placeInQueue(operation)
}
```

I hope this helps someone :) 
Please feel free to post concerns to this solution, or a better solution if you have any..